# Perfect numbers array in one expression

Tags: ruby

I'm trying write a script that will print an array of [perfect numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number/). The hard part is that I have to do this only in one expression (line).

I searched ruby-doc for some useful methods but I didn't find anything about perfect numbers, so I only managed to do this using two functions:

```
def is_perf(n)
n == (1...n).select {|i| n % i == 0}.inject(:+)
end

def perfects(range)
(array = (2..range).to_a).each{|p|array.delete_if{|x| is_perf(x)==false }}
end
```

Can somebody help me squeeze this in just one line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example like this:

```
(2..1000).select { |p| p == (1...p).select {|i| p % i == 0}.inject(:+) }
=> [6, 28, 496]
```

Edit: slightly shorter version, as suggested by @steenslag.